# webpack sass-loader load only neccessary .scss files.

Tags: sass, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to only load the appropriate .scss files? For some reason even though a react component isn't being used on a page the .scss file is still being included in my css.

I am currently using ExtractTextPlugin since I also want sourcemaps to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [react-proxy-loader](https://github.com/webpack/react-proxy-loader) It will allow you to load components and their dependancies on demand.

I'm assuming what is happening for you right now is all your code is being delivered as one or two bundles, so it makes since that some components that may not be in use (along with their required css) would still be included with the bundle.